# Angular-Formly : Adding Form fields dynamically on user click

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How would I go about adding the capability in the form so that the user can add more input fields by clicking the "Add". This using the angular formly library.

Here is an example of the exact feature but done using only angularjs.

[Adding form fields dynamically](http://www.shanidkv.com/blog/angularjs-adding-form-fields-dynamically)

Comment: Actually, what you want from that dynamic form?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/repeating-section it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @kentcdodds , I will look into the sample.

Comment: I am looking to create a basic, integrated form builder. I'm stuck in the middle with no way to add a new field and model. It seems I am missing something. fieldTransform seems it will do it, but it eludes me thus far: http://jsbin.com/kaluya/6/edit?js

Comment: Do I push a new field object, or copy of one, and do the same with the model onto vm.fields and vm.model? Inside of fieldTransform?

Comment: @kentcdodds, i looked at the repeat section example , and created a custom type to add input on clicking "Add" button. How can I access the parent controller from with in the custom type controller, as the logic to add the fields is in the parent controller.  Here is a link to the github gh-pages  http://masoodgit.github.io/ngJsonForms/app/

Comment: @Anonymous have you tried using $parent?

Comment: I could not understand. what you actually want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4BKHFWG0HnmhZ4rBjG5?p=preview)

Here is an example of what you need. As you can see in the plunker, there is a `TextArea` which can be created dynamically on button click. The created `TextAreas` can also be removed with the `remove` button click.

See the **HTML** below

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addNewChoice()" value="ADD QUESTION">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="field in choiceSet.choices track by $index">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model=" choiceSet.choices[$index]"></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> REMOVE
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the **JS** will be as below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('inspectionController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.choiceSet = {
    choices: []
  };
  $scope.quest = {};
  $scope.choiceSet.choices = [];
  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    $scope.choiceSet.choices.push('');
  };
  $scope.removeChoice = function(z) {
    $scope.choiceSet.choices.splice(z, 1);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 11):

I put simple example.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
   $scope.data ={
       names:[{ name:""}]
   };
  
  $scope.addRow = function(index){
    var name = {name:""};
       if($scope.data.names.length <= index+1){
            $scope.data.names.splice(index+1,0,name);
        }
    };
  
  $scope.deleteRow = function($event,name){
  var index = $scope.data.names.indexOf(name);
    if($event.which == 1)
       $scope.data.names.splice(index,1);
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="name in data.names track by $index">
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.names[$index].name"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="deleteRow($event,name)" value="Delete" ng-show="$index != 0"></td>
     </tr>
   </table> 
    <span>{{data|json}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellet answer and its working even when i delete one of the row in between.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example works also deleting in any order:

http://plnkr.co/edit/c0FbjBJkHtDYRKslz0iq?p=preview

or:

**some html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="oneApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-click="addNewRow()">Add row</button>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in tablerows track by $id(row)">
        <td ng-model="tablerows[$index]">
                <input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="removeRow($index)" type="button">
                  Delete
                </button>
            <td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('oneApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.tablerows = [];

    $scope.addNewRow = function () {
        var row_id;
        var tablerows = $scope.tablerows;
        if(tablerows.length > 0){
            row_id = tablerows[tablerows.length-1];
            row_id = row_id +1;
        }else{
            row_id = 0;
        }
        $scope.tablerows.push(row_id);
    };

    $scope.removeRow = function (index) {
        $scope.tablerows.splice(index,1);
    };
    }
);
```