# convert JSON format string array into real JSON array object in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, web-services

I'm trying to send to a web a JSON witch contains several 'objects' (there are no real objects yet).

This is my array:

```
$scope.atributs = [];
```

When I click on the button this is executed:

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
                        var newRow = {
                            nomAtribut: "",
                            tipus: "",
                            mida: "",
                            prioritat: "",
                            obligatori: "",
                            observacions: ""
                        }
                        $scope.atributs.push(newRow);
                    }
```

Then I have a second one button, when I click it this is happening:

```
$scope.sendRow = function(){
                        var d = {
                                    'nomAtribut': 'Saab',
                                    'tipus': 'String',
                                    'mida': '15',
                                    'prioritat': '1',
                                    'obligatori': 'No'
                                };
                        $http.post("http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/alta", angular.toJson(d)).success(function(data){
                            $scope.status = data;
                        })
                    }
```

For testing I'm sending one single string JSON transforming it to real JSON object. It's my first angular project, I'm not sure if i did it ok? How I should do it?

Regards

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your variable in `sendRow` is still an object, not a string. Why do you want to try and create a string and then parse it to JSON?

Comment: I want to make a JSON. inside this JSON put all the 'rows' from the 'atributs' array

Comment: do you see my example?

Comment: I'm looking at it. I'm on the phone now, I'm sorry. But looks useful I will try it

Comment: @hadiJZ I tryed your example but it's not working

Comment: @proktovief please explain more until i can help you.

Comment: @hadiJZ this is what is sending to the web service: {"atributs":[[object Object]]}

Comment: where you init atributs array?

Comment: i put sample here. hope that help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105162/discussion-between-proktovief-and-hadijz).

Comment: @hadiJZ sorry, but  where is the example? Regards

Answer (score 0):

I put simple example.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
   $scope.data ={
       atributs :[{
         nomAtribut: "",
         tipus: "",
         mida: "",
         prioritat: "",
         obligatori: "",
         observacions: ""}]
   };
  
  $scope.addRow = function(index){
    var row = {
         nomAtribut: "",
         tipus: "",
         mida: "",
         prioritat: "",
         obligatori: "",
         observacions: ""};
       if($scope.data.atributs.length <= index+1){
            $scope.data.atributs.splice(index+1,0,row);
        }
    };
  
  $scope.sendRow = function(){
     $http.post("http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/alta",$scope.data).
         success(function(data){
                            $scope.status = data;
                        })
        }
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="name in data.atributs track by $index">
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.atributs[$index].nomAtribut"></td>
         <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.atributs[$index].tipus"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.atributs[$index].mida"></td>
        <br>
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.atributs[$index].prioritat"></td>
         <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.atributs[$index].obligatori"></td>
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="data.atributs[$index].observacions"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="addRow($index)" value="Add" ng-show="$last"></td>
     </tr>
   </table> 
    <span>{{data|json}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want like this?