# How can i create object once we have values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to javascript so i dont know how to create object once we have values dynamically , so below code i have `fullName` and `workerKey` from `dataItem` now i want to create object `selectedOwners` with values of `fullName` and `workerKey`.

How can i achieve that task ?

ctrl.js

```
  var selectedOwners = {};
  $scope.addProcessOwner = function(dataItem){
    var fullName = dataItem.fullName;
    var workerKey = dataItem.workerKey;
    console.log('WORKER KEY', workerKey);
  }
```

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, as per comments:

```
var list = [];   
$scope.addProcessOwner = function(dataItem){
       var selectedOwners = {"fullname":dataItem.fullName,"workerKey":dataItem.workerKey};
    list.push(selectedOwners);
    }

// use list to populate output
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't have to quote the object keys. Ex: `{ fullName: dataItem.fullName, workerKey: dataItem.workerKey }`.

Comment: And `Object.assign` will copy *everything* from `dataItem`, not just the selected properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer is it good approach later i have to assign workeyKey to the form field `$scope.processDTO.processOwnerWorkerKey` and fullName to  `$scope.processDTO.prcsOwner` ther will be multiple selections of owners

Comment: @Mike C: yes, kind off stuck with using quotes

Comment: @TaranJ What do you mean you're "stuck with using quotes?" The language doesn't force you to. That's what I was saying.

Comment: @hussain: you can simply use it as selectedOwners["fullname"] or selectedOwners.fullname to assign them to the form field

Comment: @Mike C: agreed. I mean I'm stuck with using it that way, for I use selectedOwners["fullname"] and selectedOwners[fullname] means something else.

Comment: @TaranJ You're not making sense. You don't need to use brackets *or* quotes. Just do "dot name". Ex: `selectedOwners.fullName`. That's the exact same thing as `selectedOwners["fullName"]`.

Comment: @Mike: read my comments above for hussain. I know dot notation :). just that I prefer using quotes.

Comment: Thanks all of you it helped alot and i got the values assigned to object properties.

Comment: @TaranJ Then don't say you're "stuck" with them. You're not stuck with them, you prefer them.

Comment: one issue i see its creating everytime new object lets say if user select 3 different owners i want to display all three on the form but in current case its only populating last one

Comment: @Mike: yes thanks, 'prefer' was the word I was looking for :p. Hussain: you can push all 'selectedOwners' into an array and display them all, editing this answer, check it out

Answer (score 1):

You use an *object initializer*:

```
selectedOwners = {
    fullName: dataItem.fullName,
    workerKey: dataItem.workerKey
};
```

The object initializer is the `{...}` bit. Each of those two things inside it is a *property initializer*. The part before the `:` is the name, the part after is the value, which can be the result of any expression.

In your code, you'd *already* created the object (`var selectedItem = {};`). The code above will *replace* that object. If you just wanted to add to it, you'd just use assignment:

```
selectedItem.fullName = dataItem.fullName;
selectedItem.workerKey = dataItem.workerKey;
```

Which you use depends on whether it matters that you not create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You have already created the object so all you need to do is add the values into it.

```
    var selectedOwners = {};
    $scope.addProcessOwner = function(dataItem){
        selectedOwners.fullName = dataItem.fullName;
        selectedOwners.workerKey = dataItem.workerKey;
        //This will print out the newly populated object
        console.log(selectedOwners);
    }
```

Comment: That code doesn't *add* values to the object the OP created. It creates a *new* object.

Comment: Edited it to take into account what you stated. Realized you were correct and that it would re-create the object instead of actually adding the values to the already created one