# How to repeat duplicate objects using ng-repeat in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code.

```
$scope.data=[];
$scope.data=[{"label":"name","type":"string"},{"label":"email","type":"string"}];
$scope.addFields = function (field) {
   $scope.data.push(field);
  };
```

This is my html:-

```
<div ng-repeat="eachItem in data">
<input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields(eachItem)"/>
    <label>{{eachItem.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="fieldValue"/>
</div>
```

when i click add  button push one more object into `$scope.data` array like

```
 $scope.data=[{"label":"name","type":"string"},{"label":"email","type":"string"},{"label":"name","type":"string"}];
```

In the above i got an error

```
angular.min.js:102 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=nestedField%20in%20fie…%2C%22type%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A355%22%7D
at Error (native)
```

I have duplicate objects after adding. because i want to repeat label names using ng-repeat in angularjs.First i have output like this

OutPut:-

```
name   textbox
email  textbox
```

After add button click Output:-

```
name   textbox
email  textbox
name   textbox
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use track by $index

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.data=[];
$scope.data=[{"label":"name","type":"string"},{"label":"email","type":"string"}];
$scope.addFields = function (field) {
   $scope.data.push(field);
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="item item-checkbox">
   <div ng-repeat="eachItem in data track by $index">
<input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields(eachItem)"/>
    <label>{{eachItem.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You @hadiJZ. I Have data Like this $scope.data=[{"label":"name","type":"textbox"},{"label":"name","type":"textbox"}]; when i enter data in first textbox and also effected in second textbox. i use ng-model in textbox . So How to differentiate these two textboxes.

Comment: this answer may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Answer (score 3):

Use `track by` for this [purpose](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

```
<div ng-repeat="eachItem in data track by $index">
<input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields(eachItem)"/>
    <label>{{eachItem.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="eachItem.value" />
</div>
```

You also able to use `track by` with your custom filed, like `id`, or whatever

**Important**: It's better to use `track by` in each `ng-repeat`, cause it's improve `ng-repeat`'s performance ([read more](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)).

*But avoid to use `track by` in `ng-options` and other cases when you use `select as .. for ...` construction* ([read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions))

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0c5p38dt/3/)

Comment: once check the jsFiddle , i placed ng-model="eachItem.value"

Comment: @durgasivakishoremopuru tnx, update link to the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You have to ensure that items in the array have an unique key. If that is not possible you can use `track by $index` in the ng-repeat.

Check the details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)