# How to push named Json Array Into Json Object

Tags: angularjs

I want to push below data. I want order the items, it consists of     following fields:

```
var OrderItem = {"itemid":item.itemid,"itemname":item.itemname,"qty":1,"itemprice":item.itemprice};
```

But I want to Store Like this

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "itemid": 50,
            "itemname": "sample",
            "itemprice": 124,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "itemid": 52,
            "itemname": "sample",
            "itemprice": 124,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Controllers:

```
 $scope.addnew=function(item){        
  var OrderItem= {"itemid":item.itemid,"itemname":item.itemname,"qty":1,"itemprice":item.itemprice};     
        NewOrderService.addOrderitems(OrderItem);
    }

}
```

Services:

```
servctrl.service("NewOrderService", function(NewOrderFactory) {

    this.addOrderitems = function(orderitemnew) {
         NewOrderFactory.AddOrdernew(orderitemnew);
    }  
});
```

Factorys:

```
factmodule.factory("NewOrderFactory",function(){

  var orderitemsnew=[];

  return {
     AddOrdernew:function(orderitemnew){
        orderitemsnew.push(orderitemnew);
     }  
   }
});
```

How to Achieve this?

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably like this?

```
factmodule.factory("NewOrderFactory",function(){

    var orderitemsnew={
        items = [];
    };

    return{
        AddOrdernew:function(orderitemnew){
            orderitemsnew.items.push(orderitemnew);
        },
        getOrderItemsNewList: function() {
            return orderitemsnew;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank You So Much. huan feng Its Working For  Me.