# I want to push blank record in $scope.planlist=[] but shows identical behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to push each blank record in `$scope.planlist=[]` and  iterate over in html to show its template but when i fill record each record shows identical behaviour means each property cant bind with index may be  means properties cant uniquely defined

```
$scope.listOfPlans=[];

$scope.planrecord={name:"",age:""};
```

pushing like this

```
 $scope.listOfPlans.push(planrecord);
```

I want to fill each record in template so that each property can saved in unique list or object in respective index of array

Comment: Can you tell me how you are iterating your data?

Comment: also shows Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=ai%20in%20as&p1=object%3A01I

Comment: you are using ng-repeat? if yes then try "track by $index".   like ng-repeat="data in data track by $index"

Comment: already put this track by $index :@

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Comment: give your code or a demo in fiddle

Comment: actally using track by $index all recored template shows but when try to fill property of one plan like name then each name field in all plans filling at same time and any changes also

Comment: template ////    <div><span ng-click="addme();">add more</span></div>
<div ng-repeat="a in planList track by $index">
<div><input type="text" ng-model="a.planname"><input type="text" ng-model="a.price"></div>
</div>

Comment: code ///    $scope.planList=[];

$scope.record={planname:"",price:""};


addPlan(){

 $scope.as.push($scope.a);

}

Comment: see the link(above) and answer(below) given by SSH. It might help you.

Comment: okay thnku im trying :)..

Comment: thanku all :)  i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create new object in that function body.
for more info see this [Angular-Formly : Adding Form fields dynamically on user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088)

also see this answer [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

like this.

```
 $scope.add = function(){
   var newObject = {name:"",age:""};
   $scope.listOfPlans.push(newObject);
 }
```