# dynamically create add form clicking add button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms

I want to create dynamic form field after i clicked to add row button.

```
<form name="form" class="form-validation form-inline" >
<div class="form-group">

    {!!
    Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name','data-ng-model'=>'name','required'=>'required'])
    !!}

    {!!
    Form::text('description',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description','data-ng-model'=>'description'])
    !!}

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default " ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
            data-ng-click="addTag()">
        Add
    </button>
</div>
```

Add row

```
  <div ng-repeat="input in form">
                                <form name="form" class="form-validation form-inline">
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        {!!
                                        Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name','data-ng-model'=>'input.name','required'=>'required'])
                                        !!}

                                        {!!
                                        Form::text('description',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description','data-ng-model'=>'input.description'])
                                        !!}

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default " ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
                                                data-ng-click="addTag()">
                                            Add
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                                    </div>
```

And the controller section is like after edited.
How should i add them in to database?
Angularjs controller:

```
$scope.addTag = function () {
    var tag = {
        name: $scope.name,
        description: $scope.description
    };

    $http.post('tags', tag)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log('www.sabin.info.np');
            $scope.tags = data;
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.description = '';
        }).error(function (err) {
        console.log('error');
    });
};
```

and the code that i have edited is:

```
 $scope.form = [];
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.form.push({
        name: '',
        description: ''
    });
}
```

[add row field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu5g3.jpg)

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize the scope of the input form by specifying an array of object. Ex:

```
$scope.form = [];
```

After that, simply add this function to your controller :

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
   $scope.form.push({
      name: '',
      description: ''
   });
}
```

And use ng-repeat to iterate the form

```
<div ng-repeat="input in form">
   <input ng-model="input.name" />
   <input ng-model="input.description" />
</div>
```

[UPDATED]

So, I supposed you want to send the data that was inputed in each row to the backend with the endpoint of `/tags`. Here's how:

Actually all the form data was stored in `$scope.form`, which is an array of object with `name` and `description` attributes inside each of the object. So if you want to access the name/description value of the first row, you can access the value through `$scope.form[0].name` and `$scope.form[0].description`.

So the right method of sending the data is :

In HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in form">
    <input ng-model="input.name" />
    <input ng-model="input.description" />
    //You pass the input object throught the function params
    <button ng-click="addTag(input)">Add Tag</button> 
</div>
```

In Controller :

```
$scope.addTag = function (input) {
    $http.post('tags', input)
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log('www.sabin.info.np');
        }).error(function (err) {
        console.log('error');
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you so much and i want to ask another question that i am facing problem

Comment: this is the code for posting to database, how to push the data to database
$scope.addTag = function () {
        var tag = {
            name: $scope.input.name,
            description: $scope.input.description
        };

        $http.post('tags', tag)
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log('www.sabin.info.np');
                $scope.tags = data;
                $scope.input.name = '';
                $scope.input.description = '';
            }).error(function (err) {
            console.log('error');
        });
    };

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please update your question for this one? I just doesn't get what you're asking about.

Comment: i want to perform add using angularjs in laravel.
i don't know how to get the data in angularjs controller from form.