# ng-change for dynamically created DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I writing an application where cost of employees is calculated. 
User can add multiple member and input their cost and days for that I am using JQuery `clone()` function.

Also on the change of input I am binding `ng-change` funtion which for some reason doesn't work for the dynamically created elements.

You see the behaviour here:
http://codepen.io/amigoo/pen/bepgQe

Comment: Is there a reason you have to create the elements dynamicly? Why not use ng-if on the elements so they'll only be available under a condition.

Comment: @PetterPettersson What if user wants to add 100+ members?

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Comment: @SSH But I would also like to know why ng-change is not working in my code.

Comment: I think that you should compile html code that you add. and for this must use angular.

Comment: You've completely missed the point of angular, there is no need for all that jquery boilerplate code. The reason it's not working is because angular does not know about the elements jquery added. I suggest you read a little about angular.

Answer (score 0):

You have compile your dynamically created elements like this, then only they will be updated in angular scope

```
var angularCloned = $compile($cloned)($scope);
```

and then append it to your parent

```
$(".add-member-section").append(angularCloned );
```

Comment: It says `scripts.js:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: $compile is not defined`

Comment: Are you passing `$compile` service while defining your angular controller like other services `$http` etc.? You will have to do that to make it work

Comment: Possible for you to make it work in the codepen here: http://codepen.io/amigoo/pen/bepgQe