# Split <input type="text"> using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Happy day everyone,

I have started to work on angular-seed project. I have found [jsfiddle with TODO example](http://jsfiddle.net/8qv1Lpcj/11/) and would like to add another <`input type-"text">`

Is there any ways to split <`input type-"text">` to make it look like two `<input type-"text">` in the same row? My idea is similar to this [jsfiddle made with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/f5gogmac/5/), where merged string should be added to the `<li>` element

many thanks,

**app.html**

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="enteredName" />
        <button ng-click="addName()">Add</button>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in names">
                {{ name }}
                <button ng-click="removeName(name)">&times;</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['batman', 'grumpy', 'yulu'];

    $scope.addName = function(){
        $scope.names.unshift($scope.enteredName);   
    }

    $scope.removeName = function(name) {
        var i = $scope.names.indexOf(name);
        $scope.names.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Comment: You'd do it exactly the same way it's done in the JSFiddle. Make two input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to make it *"look like"* two inputs, you actually use 2 inputs and change your array of strings to an array of objects with only slight changes in the view.

```
 $scope.names = [{first: 'bat',last: 'man'}];
```

View

```
<input type="text" ng-model="enteredName.first" />
<input type="text" ng-model="enteredName.last" />
<button ng-click="addName()">Add</button>
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="name in names">
      First: {{ name.first }} Last: {{ name.last }}
      <button ng-click="removeName(name)">&times;</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TeKoA1XNiognWX2Ns4vU?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: you just nailed it! much obliged m8