# How do I generate dynamic variable name in my controller and pass the variable to ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, variables, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I generate dynamic variable name in controller and pass the variable to ng-repeat?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470928/angular-formly-adding-form-fields-dynamically-on-user-click/35603088#35603088

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check.

Answer (score -1):

You can use math.random, here I'm adding 30 random numbers where each value can have a possibility of being from 0 to 30.

```
$scope.randomArrayNumbers = [];

for (i = 0, len = 30; i<len; ++i){

    $scope.randomArrayNumbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1);
}

console.log($scope.randomArrayNumbers);
```

Comment: Hi., Here you are generating random numbers. But my case, I need to generate dynamic variable name and pass to ng-repeat.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but now all you have to do is
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="random in randomArrayNumbers">{{random}}</li>
</ul>

Comment: Sorry. I think i am confusing you. I will explain.

Comment: I want to append child node to parent node when clicking parent node. There is many parent nodes. If i click another parent node, I can able to append the child for corresponding parent node. But what happened, both the child nodes has updating since I am using same scope variable. It is not dynamic. For this case I need to create dynamic variable name and it should work for particular child.