# Add rows by button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a template with form.

```
<div class="row">
  <select name="tvParam+{{paramIndex}}}" class="form-control col-md-3" [(ngModel)]="selectedParam[paramIndex]">
    <option *ngFor="let param of parametrs">{{param}}</option>
  </select>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tvParamValue" [(ngModel)] = "paramet[paramIndex]" (change)="passData()">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRow()">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to repeat this part of my form when I click on button. 
How can I do this in Angular2+?

**UPD**

I tried to use another one component. But how can I pass data between them?
I have to pass selectedParam and text, entered in input.

BaseComponent:

```
 <div *ngFor="let re of paramRows">
  <app-home></app-home>
 </div>
```

Component with row template

```
    <div class="row mt-3">
<select name="tvParam+{{paramIndex}}}" class="form-control col-md-3" [(ngModel)]="selectedParam[paramIndex]">
<option *ngFor="let param of parametrs">{{param}}</option>
</select>
<div class="col">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tvParamValue" [(ngModel)] = "paramet[paramIndex]">
</div>
<div class="col-auto">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRow()">+</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a component and insert in `<div *ngFor="let re of repeated"> your-component-tag </div>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new row in a table using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504966/add-new-row-in-a-table-using-ng-repeat)

Comment: That was to AngularJS not Angular2+ as @Vitakuu asked

Comment: Like @Viszman stated, iterate over an array using `*ngFor` and on every button click handler add an item to that array. Give it a shot, if you get stuck come back and update your question with the specifics of what is not working and the updated code.

Comment: check out this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qrvlh

Comment: And how can I share data between components?@Viszman

Comment: It works but when i change selection at dropdown list it changes at all rows. @Vega

Comment: Updated code @Igor